# Query with eloquent

Tags: laravel

I try to display the rugdy matchs from a structure

my table team (Equipe):

- name_team
- structure_id

my table Match (Rencontre)

- team_1 ( equipe_domicile_id)
- team_2 (equipe_visiteur_id)

i would like to display to the user the matchs from his team ( team 1 or team 2 ) but with the following query the where condition seems to doesn't work . someone knows how to do that ? thanks a lot in advance

here my query :

```
$rencontres = Rencontre::crossJoin('equipe')
            ->where(['structure_id' => Auth::user()->structure->id])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `whereHas()`:

```
Rencontre::whereHas('equipe', function($q) {
               $q->where(['structure_id' => Auth::user()->structure->id]);
           )}
           ->get();
```

Make sure you have `equipe` relationship defined.

Comment: thanks for your reply Alexey ! i get now : Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::equipe()

Comment: @MathieuMourareau as I said, you need to have a relationship between matches and teams to be defined. Use that relationship.

Comment: i made the relation in the model now ! SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'rencontre.equipe_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `rencontre` where exists (select * from `equipe` where `rencontre`.`equipe_id` = `equipe`.`id` and (`structure_id` = 6)))   . the the table rencontre i have equipe_home_id and equipe_visitor_id

Comment: i need to match the query to equipe_home_id or equipe_visitor_id